# Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0. 1:6379

Tags: redis, socket.io

throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^

```
Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.
1:6379
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1016:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1039:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1138:14)
```

Code:

```
var app = require('express')(); 
var server = require('http').Server(app); 
var io = require('socket.io')(server); 
var redis = require('redis'); 
server.listen(8890);
io.on('connection', function (socket) { 
    console.log("client connected"); 
    var redisClient = redis.createClient();
    redisClient.subscribe('message'); 
    redisClient.on("message", function(channel, data) { 
        console.log("new message add in queue "+ data['message'] + " channel"); 
        socket.emit(channel, data); 
    }); 
    socket.on('disconnect', function() { redisClient.quit(); }); 
});
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your code I've created a project with your code and it's working fine, I think there is an issue with your redis  you may not have redis in your localhost or your are not started the redis server

Comment: how can start redis server?

Comment: if you are in linux or mac environment just run redis-server
and if you are in windows go to the folder you have installed redis and run redis-server.exe

Comment: FYI do not put code in comments, put it in the question, properly formatted.